# spring mongo data exception, with configuring via xml

Tags: spring, mongodb

hopefully someone can help me with this. I am working on a spring-data with mongo, but somehow it gives me a runtime error:

> Oct 02, 2012 8:15:24 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
>   INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@54d57bcb: startup date [Tue Oct 02 20:15:24 SGT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
>   Oct 02, 2012 8:15:24 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
>   INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [mongodb/configuration/mongo-config.xml]
>   Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [mongodb/configuration/mongo-config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.MongoNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationExtension
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>       at parseXML.main(parseXML.java:36)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.MongoNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationExtension
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1426)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1421)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
>       ... 19 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationExtension
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
>       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2002)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:129)
>       ... 26 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtension
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
>       ... 32 more

My mongo-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
<mongo:db-factory dbname="testuserexample" host="localhost" port="27017" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>

<mongo:repositories base-package="mongodb.repository" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you add spring-data dependency into classpath?

Comment: hi! Yes, I did add these 3 items:

Comment: I mean did you add spring-data jar? It seems it couldn't find some classes.

Comment: hm, i got these 3 jars:
spring-data-common-core.jar
spring-data-document-core.jar
spring-data-mongodb.jar

in my project dependencies. Is that what i should be looking for?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Maven you should add depency to the spring-data-mongodb library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.M1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid using maven since I don't know how that works and stuff. So I tried it just now, and it worked ;p. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error too.
I found a solution for me.
The problem was that I've changed my pom.xml and setted last version explicitly (1.1.0.RELEASE) for both dependencies :

1. spring-data-mongodb
2. spring-data-commons-core

I get the same exception : NoClassDefFoundError: ...RepositoryConfigurationExtension

I've removed the second dependence in my pom.xml because the first "spring-data-mongodb" add an implicite dependence for the second one.
So, now Maven grab automatically spring-data-commons-core dependence (1.4.0.RELEASE) and it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven this is the only dependancy that is required:-

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
<version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Configuration needed in the application context file:-

```
 <bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
        <property name="host" value="localhost" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
        <constructor-arg value="test" />
    </bean>
```